# 502 status for my nginx proxy_pass setting

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

Cloudflare have managing my domain, and my DNS records points to my AWS web server public IP.

I'm tried to host both of Node.js (Express) server and Nginx static page.

My Nginx conf in the conf.d/:

```
# Main
server {
    server_name 3.79.x.x;
}

# Express
server {
    server_name server.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    }
}
```

I was expecting that my server.example.com subdomain can successfully take responsibility of my express server which emiting from localhost:3001.